# Ways to cast more than one (standard action) spell in one round without storing spells in magical items

Tags: pathfinder-1e

Is there a way to cast more than one Standard Action (SA) spells in one round. I know there are ways to store spells in magical items, this is not what I am looking for. I read through some stuff like *[Haste](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/h/haste)* and *mythic [Amazing Initiative](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/mythic/mythic-heroes)*.

Haste:

> nor does it actually grant an extra action, so you can't use it to cast a second spell or otherwise take an extra action in the round.

Amazing Initiative:

> This additional standard action can't be used to cast a spell.

I am also not looking for that are already swift action spells, but is there a way of making a SA spell a swift action spell? But I doubt that.

Comment: Haste does not grant you another standard action. It does increase your possible effectiveness however by granting an increased movement speed, or additional attack during a full attack (which is not a standard action but a full round action). The mythic  Amazing Initiative while it does grant an extra standard action, they were worried people would be trying to get off extra spells (which tend to be more powerful than attacks).

Comment: There is a question elsewhere about the maximum number of spells per round that can be cast; but I've had no luck tracking it down - that had information about other methods of spellcasting, like contingency, Magus spell abilities and the like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the only way this was ever intended to be done is through the metamagic feat [Quicken Spell](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/metamagic-feats/quicken-spell-metamagic---final), as that is the only skill or feat that does explicitly state that you can still cast a spell the same round; the quickened spell you choose is a swift action, and it allows you to still cast a "regular", standard-action spell. However, the quickened spell requires a spell slot that is **four** spell slots higher than the spell you want to quicken.

I think there are also a select few spells that have a casting time of less than one standard action, but they really are few and far between; the only other way that comes to mind would be certain classes' Supernatural abilities, which often mimick spells, but sometimes use less than a standard action. If they allow you to cast another spell that round depends on the skill description, though.

The reason most skills that allow you to cast a spell faster than it was intended do not allow the casting of another spell that round, is simply to avoid abuse: If you were allowed to do that, you could cast another quickened spell **and** another standard action spell the same round, which gives you a total of **three** spells per round that you can cast, which clearly would be OP.

Comment: What about quicken metamagic rod? It IS a magic item, but it doesn't store spells.

Comment: the quicken metamagic rod states that you can cast a spell **as if you had the quicken metamagic spell feat**. Thus, it can be used to cast one more spell with a casting time of 1 Standard Action, just as if you had actually cast a quickened spell, but it does not allow you to cast more spells - you *either* use your own quickened spell, *or* you use the quicken metamagic rod, not both.

Comment: Yes, I meant you can use metamagic rod instead of taking a feat.

Answer (score 0):

The [contingency](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/contingency) spell allows the activation of a spell from a trigger, event, word etc this could be used to cast another SA spell in the same round.